# Do I need to add header file in XCODE if framework is added via pod?

Tags: xcode, opencv, cocoapods

I have been trying to add `opencv` in my xcode project.

I can successfully add opencv through pod like explained here https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV

However, once installed, I cannot do

```
import CV or import OpenCV
```

In fact when I just type `import c` it doesn't give me any code hint for `open cv`. That means opencv is not installed properly.

**My Question**

Do I still need to add `header file` even I have added the framwork via pod?

While I had added `facebook` from pod, I didn't need the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , When we use framework with pod then we need not to add header file in the project. Just run your project once after installing pod then you can import open cv in your project also Xcode will give hint.

Comment: Did you run your project after installing framework with pod ?

Comment: Yes, I did run. All other framework like `facebook` are all ok, but not open cv.

Comment: Then you should reinstall open cv, this may help you.

Comment: I have also done that. Even created fresh project to test but no luck.

Comment: Which exact versions of Xcode and cocoapods do you have installed?

Comment: XCODE v8 and pod 1.2.0